# Stripe - Which webhook event I need to use if my recurring failed on renewal?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am using stripe payments with my .NET application. And I want to record the event if my recurring failed but not when initial payment failed, using the webhook. So which webhook event will be used in this case.
I have checked `payment_intent.payment_failed` event but it also triggered on initial payment failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd listen for `invoice.payment_failed`, which describes an invoice. Then on the invoice you'd look at the `billing_reason` field, which tells you if the invoice was for the initial payment or a recurring one: https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-billing_reason